# Java ClassCastException taking ParameterizedType E from generic instance "new ClazzXXX<E>()"

Tags: java, class, generics, generic-programming, parametric-polymorphism

Below I pasted the example I would like to run.

I can easily get the generic class of a `StringHome` instance which extends `Home<String>`, but I can't do the same with a `new Home<String>()` instance.
How can I obtain it?

My target is making `mainKO` method works as the `mainOK` does.

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class Home<E> {
    @SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
    public Class<E> getTypeParameterClass(){
        Type type = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        ParameterizedType paramType = (ParameterizedType) type;
        return (Class<E>) paramType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    private static class StringHome extends Home<String>{}
    private static class StringBuilderHome extends Home<StringBuilder>{}
    private static class StringBufferHome extends Home<StringBuffer>{}   

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // this works fine
        mainOK();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        // this throws an error
        mainKO();
    }

    /**
     * This prints "String", "StringBuilder" and "StringBuffer"
     */
    public static void mainOK() throws Exception {
        Object object0 = new StringHome().getTypeParameterClass().newInstance();
        Object object1 = new StringBuilderHome().getTypeParameterClass().newInstance();
        Object object2 = new StringBufferHome().getTypeParameterClass().newInstance();
        System.out.println(object0.getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(object1.getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(object2.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    /**
     * This throws error:
     * Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
     */
    public static void mainKO() throws Exception {
        Object object0 = new Home<String>().getTypeParameterClass().newInstance();
        Object object1 = new Home<StringBuilder>().getTypeParameterClass().newInstance();
        Object object2 = new Home<StringBuffer>().getTypeParameterClass().newInstance();
        System.out.println(object0.getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(object1.getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(object2.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

The execution of this class prints out this:

```
String
StringBuilder
StringBuffer
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
    at org.command4j.core.commands.utils.Home.getTypeParameterClass(Home.java:13)
    at org.command4j.core.commands.utils.Home.mainKO(Home.java:46)
    at org.command4j.core.commands.utils.Home.main(Home.java:26)
```

Comment: Can you explain me why this isn't possible technically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't.**

To understand that, just make a tree of each of your object's hierarchy.

- ***StringHome***'s superclass is ***Home`<java.lang.String>`***. So when you call getGenericSuperclass() you get that superclass. Then you can get the actual type parameter ***String***.

**BUT**

- ***Home`<String>`***'s superclass is ***java.lang.Object***. Furthermore, at runtime, you lost parameter and just could know it's a ***Home*** object.

Java generics erase generic type information on compile. You won't be able to get this information at runtime.